# Objective-C library binding for Xamarin iOS Errors

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, cocoapods

I'm binding this Objective-C library - ** [SPSlideTabBarController](http://github.com/aokizen/SPSlideTabBarController) for use in my Xamarin iOS app.

I've made a few changes in my ApiDefinitions.cs file and I'm getting 3 build errors when I build my binding project. The errors are reflected in the generated file `SPSlideTabBarProtocol.g.cs`

Below are the errors:

```
1. The modifier abstract is not valid for this item
```

for this line of code:

```
[Export ("initWithTabBarItems:")]
[CompilerGenerated]
public abstract SPSlideTabBarProtocol (SPSlideTabBarItem[] tabBarItems);
```

Second error:

```
2. cannot declare instance members in a static class  <--- error right on this line

[CompilerGenerated]
    public virtual SPSlideTabBarController SlideTabBarController {
        [Export ("slideTabBarController", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        get {
            SPSlideTabBarController ret;
            if (IsDirectBinding) {
                ret =  Runtime.GetNSObject<SPSlideTabBarController> (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (this.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("slideTabBarController")));
            } else {
                ret =  Runtime.GetNSObject<SPSlideTabBarController> (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (this.SuperHandle, Selector.GetHandle ("slideTabBarController")));
            }
            return ret;
        }

    }
```

3rd error:

```
3.cannot declare instance members in a static class

[CompilerGenerated]
    public virtual SPSlideTabBarItem SlideTabBarItem { // <--- error right on this line
        [Export ("slideTabBarItem", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        get {
            SPSlideTabBarItem ret;
            if (IsDirectBinding) {
                ret =  Runtime.GetNSObject<SPSlideTabBarItem> (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (this.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("slideTabBarItem")));
            } else {
                ret =  Runtime.GetNSObject<SPSlideTabBarItem> (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (this.SuperHandle, Selector.GetHandle ("slideTabBarItem")));
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

The corresponding definitions in the ApiDefinition.cs file are:

```
1.// @protocol SPSlideTabBarProtocol <NSObject>
[Protocol, Model]
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
//[Model][Protocol]
interface SPSlideTabBarProtocol
{
    // @required -(instancetype)initWithTabBarItems:(NSArray<SPSlideTabBarItem *> *)tabBarItems;
    [Abstract]
    [Export("initWithTabBarItems:")]
    IntPtr Constructor(SPSlideTabBarItem[] tabBarItems);
}

2. // @interface SPSlideTabBarItem (UIViewController)

[BaseType(typeof(UIViewController))]
[Category]
interface UIViewController_SPSlideTabBarItem
{
    // @property (nonatomic, strong) SPSlideTabBarItem * _Null_unspecified slideTabBarItem;
    [Export("slideTabBarItem", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
    SPSlideTabBarItem SlideTabBarItem { get; set; }

    // @property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) SPSlideTabBarController * _Nullable slideTabBarController;
    [NullAllowed, Export("slideTabBarController", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
    SPSlideTabBarController SlideTabBarController { get; }
}
```

I have tried a few solutions to no avail. Could someone help me understand these errors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to resolve these errors the following ways:

```
1.The modifier abstract is not valid for this item
```

All I had to do for this one was to remove the abstract attribute from the definition like this:

From this:

```
interface SPSlideTabBarProtocol
{
// @required -(instancetype)initWithTabBarItems:
(NSArray<SPSlideTabBarItem *> *)tabBarItems;
[Abstract]
[Export("initWithTabBarItems:")]
IntPtr Constructor(SPSlideTabBarItem[] tabBarItems);
```

}

To this:

```
interface SPSlideTabBarProtocol
{
// @required -(instancetype)initWithTabBarItems:(NSArray<SPSlideTabBarItem *> *)tabBarItems;
[Export("initWithTabBarItems:")]
IntPtr Constructor(SPSlideTabBarItem[] tabBarItems);
```

}

For the other two errors, the error was due to the fact that the class was static, but it's members were not. So if the the class has been defined as static, then we need to define the members as static as well.
Below is the change:

I added a static attribute to the properties from this:

```
  [BaseType(typeof(UIViewController))]
  [Category]
  interface UIViewController_SPSlideTabBarItem
  {
// @property (nonatomic, strong) SPSlideTabBarItem * _Null_unspecified slideTabBarItem;
[Export("slideTabBarItem", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
SPSlideTabBarItem SlideTabBarItem { get; set; }

// @property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) SPSlideTabBarController * _Nullable slideTabBarController;
[NullAllowed, Export("slideTabBarController", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
SPSlideTabBarController SlideTabBarController { get; }
 }
```

To this:

```
 [BaseType(typeof(UIViewController))]
[Category]
interface UIViewController_SPSlideTabBarItem
{
    // @property (nonatomic, strong) SPSlideTabBarItem * _Null_unspecified slideTabBarItem;
    [Static] //<----static attribute added here
    [Export("slideTabBarItem", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
    SPSlideTabBarItem SlideTabBarItem { get; set; }

    // @property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) SPSlideTabBarController * _Nullable slideTabBarController;
    [Static] //<----static attribute added here
    [NullAllowed, Export("slideTabBarController", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
    SPSlideTabBarController SlideTabBarController { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2 you should change to this:

```
// @interface SPSlideTabBarItem (UIViewController)
[Category]
[BaseType (typeof(UIViewController))]
interface UIViewController_SPSlideTabBarItem
{
    // @property (nonatomic, strong) SPSlideTabBarItem * _Null_unspecified slideTabBarItem;
    [Export ("slideTabBarItem")]
    SPSlideTabBarItem Get_SlideTabBarItem();

    [Export ("setslideTabBarItem:")]
    void Set_SPSlideTabBarItem(SPSlideTabBarItem value);


    // @property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) SPSlideTabBarController * _Nullable slideTabBarController;
    [Export ("slideTabBarController")]
    SPSlideTabBarController Get_SlideTabBarController()
}
```

This is because C # only supports extension methods, but there are extended property in ObjC.